# Numero de notificaciones

Tags: laravel, notificaciones, count

necesito una ayuda, estoy trabajando con las notificaciones de laravel, a pesar que las muestro por cada registro que se hace, me gustaria mostrarlas de forma agrupada, es decir, de la siguiente manera:
[image: Notificaciones]

```
Asi es lo hago actualmente: @foreach(auth()->user()->unreadNotifications  as $notifications)
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-item" style="white-space: pre-line; ">
                <i class="fas fa-file mr-2"></i> {{ $notifications->data['contenido']  }} <!--4 new messages-->
                <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">{{ $notifications->created_at->diffforHumans()  }}</span>
              </a>
            @endforeach
```

La idea es contar notificaciones por grupo o de forma agrupada ya que al hacerlo por registros el dropdown de notificaciones se hace muy extenso y pierde la experiencia de usuario y no se puede visualizar la opcion de marcar todas como leidas.

En lo que puedan aportar, siempre se le estara agraecido.

Saludos.

Comment: Magos no somos pero imagino que la solución la tendrás en incorporar a tu tabla notificación una columna que te permita agruparlas y contarlas, digamos un clasificador del origen de la notificación: mensajes, solicitudes de amistad, reportes, etc. Se me ocurre mirando la imagen que adjuntas.

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas una columna en la tabla de notificaciones que te indique el tipo de notificacion que es y despues desde el controller cuando haces la consulta que le pasas a tu vista le haces un groupBy por tipo y devolves los datos tipo y count(*). Te paso lo que seria el codigo en tu controller (no se los nombres de tus entidades) Asumo que usas Eloquent

```
$notificaciones = Notificaciones::selectRaw('tipo, count(*)')
->groupByRaw('tipo')
->get();

return view('home',['notificaciones' => $notificaciones]);
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, por alli pensaba hacerlo, pero pense que habia otra alternativa . Excelente. Saludos.